# Use of "we mostly encourage"

Tags: phrases, word-usage

Recently I received an invitation closing with the expression "We mostly encourage you to attend her lectures." This did strike me as odd, since my intuitive understanding of "mostly" is that it refers to a majority - in this context I was interpreting it as "most of us encourage you..."

Is the usage of "mostly" in this context (i.e. to stress the encouragement) correct, or would something like "highly" be more suitable?

Comment: If I say *I mostly agree with you* that doesn't stress how ***much*** I agree with you. Quite the opposite, in fact - including the word ***mostly*** actually implies that I don't ***fully*** agree. So in your example one would suppose the writer intended to somehow "hedge" the encouragement. Perhaps "we" are a group of people, only *some* of whom endorse the encouragement. Or perhaps we only encourage you to attend *some* of her lectures. But regardless of what the writer *meant*, it's not really an idiomatically valid usage (to me, at least). He should use ***strongly*** or similar.

Comment: (Note that ***highly*** doesn't work in such contexts, but I can't easily explain why.)

Comment: The definition leaves not room for ambiguity "You use mostly to indicate that a statement is generally true, for example true about the majority of a group of things or people, true most of the time, or true in most respects". Your example means that not everyone in the group encourage you to attend the lecture. It sounds like a typo from the sender or a very bitchy way of saying the lecturer is crap.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Can you explain why is "highly" not working here?  "highly encouraged" sounds very idiomatic to me.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I though. @FumbleFingers, I would also be interested in hearing why *highly* would not work here.

Comment: I actually found thousand of hits on google with " highly encouraged to attend" written exactly like that , and usually from education related  websites. https://www.google.ca/search?q=%22higly+encouraged%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=girlV6H7JcnjjwS6u474Aw#q=%22highly+encouraged+to+attend%22&start=10

Comment: I think it's unfortunate that the misuse of the word "mostly" suggests that the writer has a limited grasp of the kind of writing style one would expect from someone working in an academic institution.

Comment: @P. O.: I'm not sure how to "explain" it, but there's no doubt that saying something is ***highly** encouraged* is a relatively recent usage that's still [far less common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+highly+encouraged%2Cis+strongly+encouraged&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20highly%20encouraged%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20strongly%20encouraged%3B%2Cc0) than ***strongly** encouraged* (esp in BrE). And for my money the "active" form ***I highly encourage** you to reconsider* is even less acceptable than the passive.

Comment: ...it's probably relevant that there's nothing at all unusual about *He is highly admired*, but almost nobody says *I **highly** admire him* - it's virtually always [*I **greatly** admire him*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+highly+admire%2CI+greatly+admire&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20highly%20admire%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20greatly%20admire%3B%2Cc0) or similar.

Comment: We really need to see the context to try to guess what led to this very strange sentence.  For example, maybe they meant "We hope you will sign up for some one-on-one sessions with Dr So-and-so during her two-week visit to our department.  Also, we will be making half a dozen copies of her book available on a rotating basis for students to read.  But most of all, we encourage everyone to attend her lectures."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Mostly* does indicate a "majority", but not necessarily a majority of people.

- I mostly agree with you.
- They mostly sell computers, but also have some tablets.
- My battery is mostly charged.

You can use the word for anything that is a fraction of the whole. In other words, "mostly" is synonymous with "for the most part".

---

That being said, "We mostly encourage you to attend her lectures" seems wrong due to the context.

Since it's an invitation, it would be unusual to display halfheartedness. It *might* make sense if there was another option that wasn't as good, but still worthwhile. For example:

> We mostly encourage you to attend her lectures, but you should also visit our website.

However, they may have meant:

> We *strongly*/*highly* encourage you to attend her lectures.

It's the difference between something being "more encouraged than" and "very encouraged"; the former implies there is something else that is encouraged.

Comment: You almost expect *We mostly encourage you to attend*, to be followed  with *But on this occasion we do not*.